# Can't move the player using GUI.Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am creating a simple game and now I am going to move my player. I want to move my player using four touch buttons for mobile. I am using `GuiTexture` buttons and using the code below. However, I am getting this error:

> The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.GUI.Button(UnityEngine.Rect, string)` has some invalid arguments"

How to fix it?

**Code**

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float movement;
    public Vector3 input;
    private float maxSpeed=15f;
    private Vector3 spawn;
    public GameObject deathparticales;
    public GUITexture Left;
    public GUITexture Right;
    public GUITexture Up;
    public GUITexture Down;
    private bool moveRight, moveLeft, moveUp, moveDown;

    // Use this for initialization       
    void Start () {
        spawn = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (GUI.Button(Rect (50,50,50,50), Left))
        {
            Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
            position.x--;
            this.transform.position = position;
        }

        if (GUI.Button(Rect (100,50,50,50), Right))
        {
            Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
            position.x++;
            this.transform.position = position;
        }

        if (GUI.Button(Rect (75,100,50,50), Up))
            {
            Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
            position.y++;
            this.transform.position = position;
        }

        if (GUI.Button(Rect (25,100,50,50), Down))
        {
            Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
            position.y--;
            this.transform.position = position;
        }

        if (transform.position.y < -1) {
            Die ();
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision death)
    {
        if(death.transform.tag == "Enemycollision")
        {
            Die();

        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider target)
    {
        if (target.transform.tag == "Target") {
        Gamemanager.completelevel();
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Instantiate(deathparticales,transform.position,Quaternion.Euler(270,0,0));
        transform.position=spawn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Left, Right, Up, Down are not strings, they are declared as GUITexture

Comment: how can I solve this? would you please correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want text to be displayed on buttons then just take "Left", "Down", "Up" and "Right" in quotes. If you want buttons with images then change GUITexture type to Texture (or Texture2D) as said here - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html